# Why are there no 'To' nor 'From' headers in the output from the internetMessageHeaders selector?

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

When I make the following call:

```
/beta/me/messages/{id}?$select=internetMessageHeaders
```

I get the following output:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('...')/messages(internetMessageHeaders)/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "...",
    "id": "AAMkAGY1Mz...",
    "internetMessageHeaders": [
        {
            "name": "Received",
            "value": "from CY1PR16MB0549.namprd16.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:903:13d::13) by DM3PR16MB0553.namprd16.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS via CY4PR06CA0051.NAMPRD06.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Fri, 16 Feb 2018 22:14:45 +0000"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

And nowhere do I find 'To' or 'From' fields in the response. Why? Is there a way to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/internetmessageheader), this property holds:

> A key-value pair that represents an Internet message header, as defined by RFC5322, that provides details of the network path taken by a message from the sender to the recipient.

Based on that description, your result looks correct to me:

```
from CY1PR16MB0549.namprd16.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:903:13d::13) 
by DM3PR16MB0553.namprd16.prod.outlook.com 
with HTTPS 
via CY4PR06CA0051.NAMPRD06.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; 
Fri, 16 Feb 2018 22:14:45 +0000
```

For the `To` and `From` addresses, you need to add `toRecipients` and `from` to your `$select` clause.

```
/beta/me/messages/{id}?$select=toRecipients,from,internetMessageHeaders
```

Comment: "From" and "To" are both headers formally defined by RFC5322, therefore I do not understand why they would not be included in the "internetMessageHeaders" selector.